# PHP - Returning Errors with $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, magento, session

I have a PHP script which will return order information from the Magento API depending upon the order ID entered. I added two additional input fields to the form for the API username and password so that they weren't stored on the PHP script file.

This works great, except I need to be able for the script to catch the error that is caused when the API username and/or password are incorrect.

Here is a successful query:

[image]

The bottom line is what was returned when clicking **Submit**. If the query is unsuccessful, the script will not return back to the initial form page and looks like this:

[image]

Please see my code below:

**Form Page**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Retrieve Order</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/matt/api.css">
    </head>
    <body>


        <form class="get_value" action="get_order.php" method="post">
            Enter username and password.
            <input type="text" name="api_user">
            <input type="password" name="api_pass"><br><br>
            Enter an order ID to retrieve the grand total order value.<br><br>
            <input type="text" name="order_id">
            <input type="submit" class="form_submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['query_result'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['query_result'];
        unset($_SESSION['query_result']);
    }
?>
```

**PHP Script**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/matt/api.css">
<?php
    $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
    $user = $_POST['api_user'];
    $pass = $_POST['api_pass'];
    $client = new SoapClient('https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    $session = $client->login($user, $pass);
    $filter = array('filter' => array(array('key' => 'order_id', 'value' => $order_id)));
    $result = $client->salesOrderList($session, $filter);

    session_start();
    if ($result) {
       foreach ($result as $returned_order) {
            $_SESSION['query_result'] = 'The grand total of order ID <b>' . $order_id . '</b> is <span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold;">£' . round($returned_order->grand_total, 2) . '</span>';
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['query_result'] = 'Order ID <b>' . $order_id . '</b> does not exist in the database.';
    }

    header('Location: xxx/enter_order_id.php');
?>
```

How can I "catch" the error so that it is returned as part of the `query_result` session variable? Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: Look into [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) blocks.

Comment: use [try](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: I did wrap the code from `session_start();` onwards in a try/catch block but the result was the same as in the second screenshot. I guess I could have done something wrong. Possibly wrapping the entire `session_start();` as well as the header code was incorrect?

Comment: A note, your `header('Location: ....)` will never work. You must set all headers before anything is outputted to the screen at all.

Comment: It's the Soap-call that needs to be wrapped inside `try/catch`. It's in that call the exception is thrown.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It does currently work when there isn't an error, or is that what you meant? I'll try that right now. Thank you.

Comment: Since you're having HTML output (`<link ....>`) above the `header('Location: ...');` statement, that redirect shouldn't work. You should get "Headers already sent". Or does your actual code look slightly different?.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've not actually seen that error before - it works when the API username and password is correct and returns back to the form file (or stays there rather). Regarding the try/catch, this now works after wrapping it around the entire code. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the variables and the statement in a try-catch exception handler. Working code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    try {

        $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
        $user = $_POST['api_user'];
        $pass = $_POST['api_pass'];
        $client = new SoapClient('https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
        $session = $client->login($user, $pass);
        $filter = array('filter' => array(array('key' => 'order_id', 'value' => $order_id)));
        $result = $client->salesOrderList($session, $filter);

        if ($result) {
           foreach ($result as $returned_order) {
                $_SESSION['query_result'] = '<span class="success_box">The grand total of order ID <b>' . $order_id . '</b> is <b>£' . round($returned_order->grand_total, 2) . '</b></span>';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['query_result'] = '<span class="error_box"><b>Error:</b> Order ID <b>' . $order_id . '</b> does not exist in the database.</span>';
        }
    } catch(exception $e) {
        $_SESSION['query_result'] = '<span class="error_box"><b>Error:</b> ' . $e->getMessage() . '</span>';
    }

    header('Location: xxx');
?>
```